# Can wss4j 2.1.* run using Java6?

Tags: java-6, wss4j

I compiled the code using the maven script provided by apache but I'm not sure it will run in Java6. Can anyone confirm whether or not this library will work with Java6?

If not naturally, then is there a way to do this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, WSS4J 2.1.x requires JDK 7. WSS4J 2.0.x works with JDK 6.

Comment: It's open source code. Can't I modify the code so that it's Java6 compliant? It appears there are only 3 major issues: 1) <> operator, 2) multi-catch, and 3) try with resources.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm just going to upgrade my environment to Java7.